# Display values in the order they are in the form field

Tags: entities, users

I created a field called *Authors*, that can take multiple values (*Users* registered on the site).
I would like to display the authors in the same order I add them in the field.

They are currently displayed with no logical order (it is neither the order they appear in the field, nor the alphabetical order, nor the UUID of the users...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found the cause of the problem : the use of *Selection list* or *Chosen* as widgets for the field.

Using the *Autocomplete* widget, it works fine : the order of the values in the back-end is conserved in the front-end.